SQL {ADD PRIMARY KEY} Error via python/sqlite3 with {c.execute("ALTER TABLE
Could anyone please help me resolve below error from Python code on Google Colab while executing an SQL query:
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connection(':memory:')
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("ALTER TABLE Persons ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID)")

ERROR
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 c.execute("ALTER TABLE Persons ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID)")
Operational error: near "PRIMARY": syntax error
Thanks,

It's not possible to add a primary key when altering a table in sqlite. (There are several other restrictions as well, so you should consult the sqlite docs on the subject). The usual work-around is to copy the existing data into a new table, then drop the old table and rename the new one.

SQLlite does not support adding a primary key field using ALTER. Try recreating the table and specify Primary Field on creation.
